# Error when exporting IFC to CSV (BlenderBIM)

Tags: error

Whenever I try to export an IFC to CSV using the "IFC CSV Import/Export" in BlenderBIM I get the following error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vpaji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\blenderbim\bim\module\csv\operator.py", line 73, in execute
    ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open(props.csv_ifc_file)
  File "C:\Users\vpaji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\blenderbim\libs\site\packages\ifcopenshell\__init__.py", line 83, in open
    raise exc(msg)
OSError: Unable to open file for reading

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

[image]

Comment: Activating the "Load from Memory" option seems to alleviate the issue - Any ideas why?

Comment: Hello ! Looks like a permission problem, are you an administrator ?

Comment: Hi @Gorgious - Yes I am, I even ran Blender as Administrator but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah there are two options:

1. Load from memory, where the active IFC project is used as the data source
2. The rather poorly named "CSV IFC File" is where you should browse to an IFC file on disc to be used as the data source.

If neither are satisfied, you will get that error.